# Detect in PHP if page is accessed with cURL or Wget

Tags: php, curl, service, wget

I have a simple PHP script which shows some information to a user. I want to shorten this information as muss as possible if the same page is requested with cURL or saved with Wget.

I saw several similar question on Stackoverflow, but they have some extras like “[I want to block cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3740703/3894752)” or “redirect a form request if…”. The answers usually tell that it is not possible to detect a cURL request reliably, since cURL lets the user change all request parameters and pretend to be a browser. Thats okay for me, I dont want to block cURL, I want to offer an extra service for a generic cURL (and Wget) request.

Comment: If your user is smart enough to automate then provide a different URL for that purpose?  i.e. separate pages for human consumption & pages for software consumption by providing an API.

Comment: He should not be required to be smart enough ;) An example service is ifconfig.io → Request via Browser: lots of information. Request via cURL: The IP address only. I want to achieve the same useful behaviour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If not configured otherwise cURL and Wget use a custom »User Agent« string for their requests.

For example `curl/7.47.0` or `Wget/1.17.1 (linux-gnu)`. You can test this easiliy on https://requestb.in.

Several applications may access the User Agent string in the request header. In PHP its available in the `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` variable.

So to detect a cURL or Wget request and offer different content, you may use

```
<?php

// Catch cURL/Wget requests
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) && preg_match('/^(curl|wget)/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
    echo 'Hi curl user!';
}
else {
    echo 'Hello browser user!';
}

?>
```

In my app I detect the cURL request and then let the process `die()` in the `if` loop. So if its just a browser, the the condition doesnt match and executes all the following PHP code.

As said before, both cURL and Wget allow the user to set an arbitrary User Agent. But for the requested service, this solution is sufficient.